# Использование функции

Tags: javascript

Большая просьба к спецам в js! Почему не работает следующий код:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function () {
        var li_elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
        for (var i = 0; i < li_elements.length; i++) {
            li_elements[i].onclick = function () {
                alert(this.innerHTML);
            }
        }
    }();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <ul>
        <li>Первый</li>
        <li>Второй</li>
        <li>Третий</li>
      </ul>
    </form>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Основная ошибка тут в том что скрипт выполняется **до того** как создаются элементы,
так что:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <ul>
            <li>Первый</li>
            <li>Второй</li>
            <li>Третий</li>
        </ul>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var li_elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

        for( var i=0; i< li_elements.length; i++) {
            li_elements[i].onclick = function() {
                alert(this.innerHTML);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Либо исправьте:

```
function () {
        var li_elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

    for( var i=0; i< li_elements.length; i++) {
                li_elements[i].onclick = function() { alert(this.innerHTML); };
    }
    }();
```

На, просто добавьте еще одни скобки и перенесите это все после создания `<ul>`:

```
(function () {
    var li_elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for( var i=0; i< li_elements.length; i++) {
        li_elements[i].onclick = function() { alert(this.innerHTML); };
}
})();
```

Answer (score -2):

Потому что вы свою функцию никак не вызываете. Вы хотя бы в тэг `BODY` поставьте

```
onload="init()"
```

И мало того, назовите свою функцию именем `init`. Тогда должно заработать.